# how to fetch data using this coding

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010

using this coding,while i give fruitId ,i need to retrieve fruitname,using this it shows some error..any one help...

```
 string constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString;



using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
 {
   using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("savefruit11", con))
    {
       con.Open();
       cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FruitsId", int.Parse(TextBox3.Text.Trim()));
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@Fruitsname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
       cmd.Parameters["@Fruitsname"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       con.Close();
       TextBox4.Text = "Fruit Name:"+cmd.Parameters["@FruitName"].Value.ToString();
      }
    }
```

Store procedure for the above code.

```
use[FruitsDB]
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
     GO
    Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[savefruit11]
    @FruitId INT,
    @FruitName VARCHAR(50) OUTPUT
    AS
    BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT @FruitName = Fruitsname
   FROM Fruits1
   WHERE FruitsId = @FruitId
  END
```

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Comment: And probably the code of the stored procedure will help also.

Comment: Use string _fruitName=cmd.ExecuteScalar();

Comment: An SqlParameter with ParameterName '@FruitName' is not contained by this SqlParameterCollection. this error displayed..

Comment: s is missing in parameter name in stored procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `cmd.ExecuteQuery` or `cmd.ExecuteScalar`

```
//To Execute SELECT Statement
ExecuteQuery()

//To Execute Other Than Select Statement(means to Execute INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE)
ExecuteNonQuery()
```

with your  udpate

s is missing in parameter name in stored procedure

Comment: Without seeing the stored procedure that may not be the correct answer.

Comment: @Md.Parvez Alam...your answer is correct i applied and i got result..Thank u..i am beginner to c#..Thank u for your valuable comment...

Answer (score 4):

```
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@Fruitsname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
   cmd.Parameters["@Fruitsname"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   con.Close();
   TextBox4.Text = "Fruit Name:"+cmd.Parameters["@FruitName"].Value.ToString();
```

Your parameter is called `@Fruitsname`, but you get it back with `@FruitName`. You have an additional `s` in the first version. Make them consistent by changing the first `@FruitsName` to `@FruitName` which will match what you have in the stored procedure.

Or, as Henk suggested in the comments create a const string to contain your parameter name so that it is consistent across all usages.

Comment: Yes, getting rid of the magic string will make life much easier by ensuring that there is only one place for the parameter name to be, and one place to change, and the same value used throughout.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following example way

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection())
    {
        string connectionStringName = this.DataWorkspace.AdventureWorksData.Details.Name;
        connection.ConnectionString =
            ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionStringName].ConnectionString;

        string procedure = "HumanResources.uspUpdateEmployeePersonalInfo";
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(procedure, connection))
        {
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            command.Parameters.Add(
                new SqlParameter("@EmployeeID", entity.EmployeeID));
            command.Parameters.Add(
                new SqlParameter("@NationalIDNumber", entity.NationalIDNumber));
            command.Parameters.Add(
                new SqlParameter("@BirthDate", entity.BirthDate));
            command.Parameters.Add(
                new SqlParameter("@MaritalStatus", entity.MaritalStatus));
            command.Parameters.Add(
                new SqlParameter("@Gender", entity.Gender));

            connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

reference from MSDN
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635144.aspx